# Find top row and left most column of table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have several tables, how can I find the left-most column range and top-most row range (not including header)?

Example, table1 occupies A55:E65, how can I return (in separate cells):

1. A55:E55 (top row)
2. A55:A65 (left most column)

I can convert it to an address with

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(table1),COLUMN(table1))&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(table1)+ROWS(table1)-1,COLUMN(table1)+COLUMNS(table1)-1)
```

Will show up as $A$55:$E$65

Trying to lookup a specific date from the table out of multiple columns:
[image]

I need to lookup a date (there are no repeats, thankfully) then return the value in a specific column in the table. It has to be from the named table, as there are multiple tables stacked on top of one another with repeat dates.

Unsure of where to go from there, thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this? What are you going to do with these?

Comment: ^^^^^ If you want to access the data in those cells, there are much easier ways.

Comment: Hi BigBen, trying to feed it into an INDEX(MATCH( to find a specific value inside the table from multiple columns; if there's a better way I'd appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: If you can add more detail about that... I echo @ScottCraner, there are much easier ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX to return the correct column or row as an array.

To get the first column in the table:

```
INDEX(table1,0,1)
```

To get the first row

```
INDEX(table1,1,0)
```

So for example, this will return the forth row in the column with `390` in the first row.

```
=INDEX(Table1,4,MATCH(390,INDEX(Table1,1,0),0))
```

[image]

And this:

```
=INDEX(Table1,MATCH(848,INDEX(Table1,0,1),0),MATCH(390,INDEX(Table1,1,0),0))
```

returns the value in the column that has 390 in the first row and 848 in the first column.

[image]

ADDRESS and INDIRECT are volatile and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: This is perfect Scott, exactly what I need...thank you.